# MYSQLI UPDATE not working/no error message/working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $upd= 'UPDATE `ready` SET `res` = "1" WHERE `id`="$id"';
    if($mysqli->query($upd)=== TRUE){
   echo "<script> alert('".$mysqli->error."');</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script> alert('".$mysqli->error."');</script>";
}
```

What I do know:

- It is resulting true, because I've set the first echo to 1 before
- No error message comes up even when setting error reporting on
- This is the correct table structure and I am not sure why it isnt updating the row :/

Any help?

Comment: @Pritamkumar, why would you enclose the a string quotation before the `$upd` ?

Comment: @Pritamkumar Have already tried that thinking I could change up them up after sitting here for awhile messing around :/

Comment: Idk guys I literally changed the column name to reserved instead of res and it worked. I don't get it. @Pritamkumar

Comment: @FreedomPride Thanks for checking it out too

Comment: You should not called ->error after success, you should try other. since error only have data if error

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed out this part.

Initialize your connection :-

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Then when you trigger your query it will work 
or you can try this method with the connection initialize

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'UPDATE `ready` SET `res` = "1" WHERE `id`="$id"')
```

Comment: I already have it initialized but It has only worked once. After I said it worked, it hasn't worked again. I have also tried your method with mysqli_query aswell

Comment: @Jimmy, could you post your full script so i can dissect and know more about the problem.